# Using a method to initialize

Tags: c#, initialization

So up until recently I've been initializing all my stuff within the main function, but this makes it (imo) pretty ugly. So I went ahead and thought instead of having me write out the initializing , I'd just have a method to do it for me which would explain itself just by its name (Create.ClassRoom()). So I went ahead and made this class with the method to do it:

```
class Create
{
    public static void ClassRoom()
    {
        Student Henry = new Student("Henry", 20);
        Student Jeff = new Student("Jeff", 18);
        Student Jessica = new Student("Jessica", 22);

        Teacher MrLopez = new Teacher("Lopez", "Math", 37);
    }
```

which would make main look much nicer:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Create.ClassRoom();

        Console.WriteLine(Henry.age);
    }
}
```

However, it says Henry doesn't exist in the current context. Now I understand this has to do with scope, but I can't seem to think or find a solution to it. Is my idea just not doable or am I missing something? I'd like it to be so that after I do Create.ClassRoom(); it would allow me to interact with whatever is initialized in there.

Comment: Where's the function definition for 'ClassRoom'?

Comment: Oops! Sorry , forgot to switch the name. I'll edit it now.

Comment: You'd want to create an instance of your class first. Something like 'ClassRoom myClass = new ClassRoom()' And then access it's methods by saying something like myClass.getNumberOfStudents()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right. It has to do with the scope. The initialized variables are not accessible outside of the CreateClassRoom() method. You'll have to return an instance of the class room to the calling method.

Refactor your class as follows:

```
class ClassRoom
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; private set; }
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; private set; }

    public ClassRoom()
    {
        this.Students = new List<Student>();
        this.Teachers = new List<Teacher>();
    }
}

class Create
{
    public static ClassRoom ClassRoom()
    {
        ClassRoom classRoom = new ClassRoom();
        classRoom.Students.Add(new Student("Henry", 20));
        classRoom.Students.Add(new Student("Jeff", 18));
        classRoom.Students.Add(new Student("Jessica", 22));

        classRoom.Teachers.Add(new Teacher("Lopez", "Math", 37));

        return classRoom;
    }
}
```

The Create.ClassRoom() method returns an instance of the ClassRoom object, using which you will be able to access the Students and Teachers in the class.

From Main(), you could access the properties as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var classRoom = Create.ClassRoom();

        Console.WriteLine("Students: ");
        foreach (var student in classRoom.Students)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}; Age: {1}", student.Name, student.Age);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Teachers: ");
        foreach (var teacher in classRoom.Teachers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}; Subject: {1}", teacher.Name, teacher.Subject);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Henry cannot be accessed by main() because it is within the scope of the function ClassRoom(). You need to make it return a Student object or better yet, create a class that has a getter and setter for the variables you want to access.